# libopus produces different results on windows and linux

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, opus

I'm using libopus to encode a `pcm` input file into a `bit` bitstream. The process is pretty mundane:

1. Create an encoder: call to `opus_encoder_create`
2. Loop through the input `pcm` file (in binary mode) by reading chunks of certain frame size and encode them using `opus_encode`
3. Write the encoded output, chunk by chunk, into a bitstream file

Since I'm controlling everyone of the following parameters:

- sample rate (from call to `opus_encoder_create`)
- voice channels (from call to `opus_encoder_create`)
- application type (from call to `opus_encoder_create`)
- bit rate (from call to `opus_encoder_ctl`)
- frame size

I was wondering **why** the output (the produced binary file) **is different** on Linux (clang & Ubuntu) and windows (clang or cl on VS2019):

- are there more parameters to the encoder I should consider?
- are there intrinsic differences that prevent libopus to behave consistently across platforms?
- is there a known toolset that would help me inspect my code? for the time being, I'm using ctl calls with GET_BITRATE etc to retrieve what setting have been applied to the encoder

Comment: Are both libraries the same version?

Comment: @szatmary Yes, they're a compilation of the same code in two different platforms (branch v1.3.1).

Comment: Are the two compiled on the same machine (same cpu architecture)?

Comment: @Damiano It's 2 different desktops. That been said, the `opus_select_arch` function (in the encoder initialization), returns the same result in both cases (namely four, i.e. support for `SSE/SSE2/SSE41/AVX` is present in both machines)